# Azure Web Job reading message from Service Bus doesnt delete message after

Tags: azure-webjobs, servicebus

The scenario here is that we have a service bus queue and a web job. The web job reads the message from the service bus queue and calls a logic up which then goes on and does other stuff.

The problem we are facing is that after the web job reads the message from the service bus, it occasionally doesn't delete it after, which constantly causes the logic app to be called and flood our database with data.

Here is the message in question as seen from azure management studio:

https://gyazo.com/7f57b460421d1bb4a69fcb8b5a9ff01f

As you can see, there is no lock time on the message. I have tried to play around with the settings to no avail.

When i manually try to delete that message from azure management studio it is also unsuccessful but there is no error message received.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I feel like this is a problem with the queue itself as opposed to a bug in our code since 2-3 tools that i have used are unable to delete this message from the queue.

It looks like the message is only deleted after a specific time (does not go to the dead-letter queue however).

Thanks

Comment: Tried to call message.Complete() in ur web job ?

Comment: yes i have tried that and it still generates more rows after. I believe this to be something to do with the concurrent threads for some reason that webjob has active.

Answer (score 1):

So just for information, i figured my own issue out. When the file scraper job runs, it puts a message in the service bus. The webjob now that runs and picks up that file stores the file that it just picked up locally as well as on blob storage.

The problem was that webjob keeps a queue of what it processes locally which was never cleared so every time the webjob run, it was processing all previous files as well.